# PHP MySQL: How to save multiple input entries in one field and display in html on different columns?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

i have the following html form fields:

- name
- mobile
- address
- email

I have this mysql table:

- record_id
- records

I want to save all the html form fields input in the records fields, and retrieve it to html table on different fields:

```
|  name  | mobile | address | email |
```

How will I do this using `php, mysql`?

Thanks!

Comment: There is so many ways to do this. Use google.

Comment: This isn’t a Q&A format question, which is what Stack Overflow is for. Break your problem down into separate steps, and then tackle them independently.

Answer (score 1):

you can try php serialization method to store multiple fields in single column.

e.g On Post request you have received $_POST data for name, mobile, address, email
capture $_POST values in array

```
$records = $_POST;
$records = array('name'=>'abc', 'mobile'=>'9874325972398', 'address'=>'test', 
'email'=>'test@test.com');
```

**serialize this array**

```
`$records_serialize = serialize($records);` `//serialize the arrray to store into DB.`
```

resulting array will be

```
a:4:{s:4:"name";s:3:"abc";s:6:"mobile";s:13:"9874325972398";
s:7:"address";s:4:"test";s:5:"email";s:13:"test@test.com";}
```

use above serialized string to insert into database

unserialize value stored into DB to use it on html pages

```
 $records = unserialize($records_serialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//to parse desired field data from $_POST array
function preg_grep_keys( $pattern, $input, $flags = 0 )
{
    $keys = preg_grep( $pattern, array_keys( $input ), $flags );
    $vals = array();
    foreach ( $keys as $key )
    {
        $vals[$key] = $input[$key];
    }
    return $vals;
}



Step 1) on form post get desired form fields you want to store in db 

      $record_data=preg_grep_keys('/name|mobile|address|email/',$_POST);

Step 2) convert to json string
      $json_string=json_encode($record_data);

Step 3) Insert into db
```